# convert UTF-8 String to ISO-8859-1 java

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have an application where i want to convert an utf-8 encoded string to ISO-8859-1 because this is the encoding of my oracle DB.

Currently this is what i'm inserting in my db:

*BelgiÃ«*

But i expect this:

*België*

When i print my string in java i get the following:
*BelgiÃ«*

Can anybody help me?

This is what i already tried:

```
System.out.println(xmlString);
Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
Charset iso88591charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(xmlString.getBytes(utf8charset));
// decode UTF-8
CharBuffer data = utf8charset.decode(inputBuffer);
// encode ISO-8559-1
ByteBuffer outputBuffer = iso88591charset.encode(data);
byte[] outputData = outputBuffer.array();

xmlt = new oracle.xdb.XMLType(con, new String(outputData, iso88591charset));
```

suggestion from the comments didn't work either:

```java
    byte[] utf8 = xmlString.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] latin = new String(utf8, "UTF-8").getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(latin);
    xmlt = new oracle.xdb.XMLType(con, bis);
```

Comment: Normally the database driver is expected to handle character encoding. Did you try simply `xmlt = new oracle.xdb.XMLType(xmlString)` ?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "UTF-8 encoded string". Do you mean you had UTF-8 bytes, decoded them to a `String` using a character encoding other than UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

Normally UTF-8 can do encoding of any Unicode code. ISO-8859-1 is capable of handling tiny fraction of them and transcoding of UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 can cause "replacement characters" (�) to appear in your text when unsupported characters are found and also there might be other issues.

Transcoding from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 dont have any problem.

I would suggest to transcode text:

```
byte[] latin1 = ...
byte[] utf8 = new String(latin1, "ISO-8859-1").getBytes("UTF-8");
```

or

```
byte[] utf8 = ...
byte[] latin1 = new String(utf8, "UTF-8").getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: i tried it and edited my question with the code i used. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: normally as i said its not good idea to convert UTF-8 String to ISO-8859-1 as it will create lot of issue and also throw error with character handling...UTF-8 itself can do encoding of any Unicode code